# how to use a dynamic array in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My  query:

```
SELECT MAX(num)
FROM (SELECT nomInteretUser,idUser,COUNT(nomInteretUser) as num
      FROM userInteret
      WHERE nomInteretUser IN ('piano','flute','chien') GROUP BY idUser
     )
```

The  goal is to change the `IN ('piano','flute','chien')` to a dynamique array
like

```
SELECT nomInteretUser, idUser, COUNT(nomInteretUser) as num
FROM userInteret
WHERE nomInteretUser IN ($array)
GROUP BY idUser
```

NB: $array is an array houw contain the list of interet

Comment: `WHERE nomInteretUser  IN('".implode("','",$array)."')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `implode()`. Try below code. You need to convert your array to string. So here we will implode it with comma separated with quotes like `','` string and use it in query.

```
$array =array('piano','flute','chien');

$string = implode("','", $array);

$query = "SELECT nomInteretUser, idUser, COUNT(nomInteretUser) as num
FROM userInteret
WHERE nomInteretUser IN ('".$string."')
GROUP BY idUser";
```

**Check online Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/566015)**

Comment: It doosn't work , there is an error with the cote ' " :

Comment: SELECT idUser,COUNT(nomInteretUser) taux FROM userInteret 
  WHERE nomInteretUser IN (' " .$string. " '), it dosn't work

Comment: always no resutat , even there is one

Comment: please paste here mysql error or if no error then paste table data and real query so we can justify where is problem. @user3070123

Answer (score 2):

You can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

`implode()` function will join arrays like: `piano','flute','chien`.

We need a single quote and the beginning and end.

So, add it before and after `implode()` like: `"'".implode("','",$array)."'"`

```
$array = array('piano','flute','chien');
WHERE nomInteretUser IN('".implode("','",$array)."')";
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/566014)

Comment: there an error in this ('".implode("','",$array)."')